# Extracting unique strings from single column in order to subset dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, label

I have a dataframe with a "Set" column indicating experimental treatments. Experiment to experiment there can be a different number of unique labels within the Set column. For example there may be 60 total rows with 4 treatments and each treatment has data in 15 rows. I need to be able to subset the dataframe based on unique labels within this column. This is an easy problem to solve by simply calling the subset() command but I need to automate it and I am struggling.

The data analysis is largely the same but the labels and n change from experiment to experiment and I need to make this script as automated as possible.

Any ideas on a good way to tell R to print the label of each unique treatment and then subset the dataframe by those unique labels so I can separate out the data?

[The image is just an example of the how the Set column would look in the overall dataset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVJAR.png)

Again I typically just do this by writing the following code block.

`T1 <- subset(df, run_id == 'treatment.1')`

`T2 <- subset(df, run_id == 'treatment.2')`

`T3 <- subset(df, run_id == 'treatment.3')`

`T4 <- subset(df, run_id == 'treatment.4')`

I need to automate this though so that I don't have to manually update the labels every experiment.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't need to, as you'd use a function with grouping capability to do whatever analysis you need to do by the `Set` variable - `aggregate`, dplyr's `group_by`, or data.table's `by=`.  If you *do* end up needing these subsets for a particular reason, you can use `split` like `split(df, df$Set)` which will give you a `list` containing each subset that you can then loop over to do tasks. Extracting T1/2/3/4 is generally not good practice because you then need to find a way to loop over T1/2/3/4, but they're separate objects now.

Comment: `split` examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278133/how-do-i-create-component-subset-dataframes-in-r-based-on-column-values

Comment: Yeah you are right! I will do it with these methods, thanks !